# Overhead of using extra thenApply methods in CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm using java 11.

Let's say I have this code snippet where we're handling the completable future response:

```
service.processAsync(context)
            .thenApply(this::doSimpleStuff)
            .thenApply(this::doAnotherExtraStuff)
            .thenApply(this::doFinalStuff)
            .exceptionally(this::handleError);
```

If I fold all my `doSimpleStuff`, `doAnotherExtraStuff` and `doFinalStuff` into one function would it make a difference performance-wise?

Will this code run faster or will this be just less readable?

```
service.processAsync(context)
            .thenApply(this::doEverythingInOneFunction)
            .exceptionally(this::handleError);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might get a performance gain which may be very negligible since you are removing the processing of thenApply(), But if all 3 methods needs to be run sequentially in any case, then why to even consider the first approach and instead create a new method which will call other 3 and use the new one.

```
service.processAsync(context, id)
        .thenApply(this::callerMethod)
        .exceptionally(this::handleError);
```

```
callerMethod() {
doSimpleStuff();
doAnotherExtraStuff();
doFinalStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Himanshu mentioned, the performance benefit gained will be negligible, so much so that you should not depend on it as justification unless you are doing something ***really*** performance intensive (in which case, there are much higher priority things to fix before trying to stick all of the functions in one methond).

But to contrast the answer that @Himanshu gave, I would encourage you to keep the functions separate. It allows you to swap out a function for another should an implementation detail need to change in the future, and it lets you keep your code base free of ad-hoc simplification functions all over the place. Those tend to be a place where bugs hide.

But truthfully, it's not much loss either direction, so do what makes sense for your situation.